# Symfony2, How to change environment?

Tags: php, symfony

I have read a lot about the clear cache command for symfony2, but I have this question :

Is `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` with `--env`, changes the environment or just clean the cache for that environment?

If only clear the cache for that environment, then what is this line mean in app.php :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

I think when I want to use Symfony2 Production Environment I have to change that line to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Am I in the right spot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The two constructor arguments for [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php) are `$environment` and `$debug`.

So, to answer your question directly, **app.php** already uses the production environment.  You'll notice that **app_dev.php** instantiates the kernel like this

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

So, the environment name that you pass to the kernel constructor maps to the environment name you'd use in console commands (i.e., the `--env`).

Does that clear it up for you?

Comment: I meant if I want to use production environment in terms of users (In Browser), I have to us `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`, right? Clear Cache won't change the environment ! Correct?

Comment: No, the environment is determined by the front controller in use - which is **app.php** by default. What I mean is that `site.com/route` is analogous to `site.come/app.php/route` where **app.php** is the front controller being used.  If you wanted switch to the dev front controller, your URL would look like `site.com/app_dev.php/route`.  Make sense? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#the-front-controller

Comment: I think the second argument (the boolean value) refers to whether the environment should be run with debug enabled or disabled

Answer (score 7):

To change the environment you've to change your front controller. Symfony2 provide by default three environments and a front controller for each one of them with a specific configuration files > [See more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#different-environments-different-configuration-files)

When you execute cache:clear command for a specific environment, it just clears the cache for the given environment. To change your environment, you've just to change your front controller (app.php / app_dev.php / app_test.php)

You can also [create new environments with a specific configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#creating-a-new-environment)