# Symfony - How to set from dev to prod?

Tags: php, symfony

I know that this is not the first post about this question, but I do it because others answers didn't solve my problem.

I tried the basic :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

But this is not the good way to do it because I still have Symfony errors...
I don't know how to rewrite errors pages :

http://le-blog-etudiant.fr/blablabla

Do you know if this Symfony error is caused by the fact that my website is still in dev mode or because my `error.html.twig` page doesn't work ?

**EDIT 1 :**

I'm using `app.php` on my site, I set `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` and I did the command : `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` but it still display Symfony's errors

Comment: Do you have an prod and/or dev config file?

Comment: Also; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904960/symfony2-how-to-change-environment

Comment: I didn't change anything in the config_prod.yml. Do I've to set something to display my error.html.twig instead of Symfony's errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to do this :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

Here is the constructor of AppKernel :

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param string $environment The environment
 * @param bool   $debug       Whether to enable debugging or not
 */
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
```

Comment: Even with false, it's still display the debug mode : "No route found"

Comment: You have actually app_dev.php and app.php. app.php is configured to work as prod environnement :
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/master/web

You can also check the link that Mazz shared in comments of your previous post.
Don't forget to `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: I did those things (I edit my question). The fact is : I spent some times to do all usual command and modification and it doesn't work, that's why I created my own question :/

Comment: Try to check if your error pages work : http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development .
Then, please do a pastbin of your app.php,

Comment: My errors doesn't display in app_dev.php, so there is a problem here ... This is my app.php : pastebin.com/jWahqj1M

Comment: Your app.php seems good. Check your loaded bundles in your AppKernel and your config to see if a dev bundle is not loaded in prod. It seems you load the webprofiler in prod. Then, try to manually remove your cache (don't forget to chmod 777, or setfacl rwx your cache folder). 
After that, I have no more idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Permission denied** here showing your problem http://le-blog-etudiant.fr

[image]

You have to give permission

```
chmod 777 -R var/cache

chmod 777 -R var/cache/*
```

Other problems then we will check...

Comment: Indeed, this one happened when I clear my cache. Thanks for your command, I did it and my website can appears now ! But I still have the same problem...

Comment: Yeah, I know :) But I asked this question because i can see Symfony errors instead of mine.. You can see it on http://le-blog-etudiant.fr/r